# Lua attempt to call method a nil value

Tags: lua

I'm lost on what I'm doing wrong here.

I have this simple code:

```
Queue = {}
Queue.__Index = Queue

function Queue.Create()
    local obj = {}
    setmetatable(obj, Queue)
    return obj
end

function Queue:PushBack(item)
end

q = Queue.Create()
print(q)
q:PushBack(1)
```

When executing this I get "attempt to call method 'PushBack' (a nil value).  However, if I change the PushBack function like this and call it accordingly it works:

```
function Queue.PushBack(q, item)
end

q = Queue.Create()
print(q)
Queue.PushBack(q, 1)
```

The code runs and executes correctly.  I understand that ":" is syntactic sugar, so it seems to me that

```
function Queue:PushBack(item)
```

would be exactly the same as

```
Queue.PushBack(q, item)
```

But it dies on me.  Does it have to do with how I'm creating the object? I'm pretty lost on this and I can't seem to figure out what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nil` signifies that the `PushBack` function is not found in the first case.

The reason your code doesn't work, is because you have unintentionally misspelt `__Index` as it should be:

```
Queue.__index = Queue
```

with `i` of `__index` being lower-case.

Once corrected, your code should work.